# CentOS/Linux Block External Port

Tags: linux, centos, port, block

Suppose I have an internal service running on port 7676, how would I (On CentOS) block port 7676 from external sources, so that it can only be accessed locally - AKA 127.0.0.1, not using, for example, 64.222.33.44 - the external IP.

Comment: You use `iptables`. Read `man iptables` to learn how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) for this. What you have go do is insert a DROP rule into the INPUT chain for packets with a destination address of your external IP 64.222.33.44 and a destination port of 7676.

Answer (score 2):

If the service software allows binding to specific IP addresses, you can bind it to `127.0.0.1` address.

This means it will listen to requests only arriving via the localhost interface.

Answer (score 2):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7676 -s 64.222.33.44 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7676 -j DROP
```